# Are these the same distributions in the statsmodels and scipy libraries?

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, statsmodels

I want to make a GLM model using `statsmodels` in python. `statsmodels.glm` supports the following distrubutions:

- <s>One-parameter exponential family</s>
- Gamma
- Gaussian
- Inverse Gaussian
- Binomial
- Negative Binomial
- Poisson
- Tweedie

I want to find the same distributions in the `scipy` library. I think these are the same:

| statsmodels ([docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/glm.html)) | scipy ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html)) |
| --- | --- |
| <s>Family</s> | <s>expon</s> |
| Binomial | binom |
| Gamma | gamma |
| Gaussian | norm |
| InverseGaussian | invgauss |
| NegativeBinomial | nbinom |
| Poisson | poisson |
| Tweedie | tweedie |

<s>I am not entirely sure if "expon" is exactly the same as "Family". How could I check if this is the case?</s> Also, I think it is wise to check them all, because I am determining the best fitting distribution using the scipy package, but then apply the statsmodels glm.

Update: I thought "Family" was a distribution (in my defense, the table is quite unclear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Family` is the parent class and not a specific distribution family.

The families for GLM in statsmodels correspond to distributions in scipy.stats (except maybe for tweedie). However the parameterization is different between GLM families and the common parameterization of the distributions, such as those in scipy.

In the latest release, the GLM and most discrete models have a `get_distribution` method that returns and instance of the corresponding scipy or scipy-compatible distribution.

For example
https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/_modules/statsmodels/genmod/families/family.html#Binomial.get_distribution
which has the same parameterization, and
https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/_modules/statsmodels/genmod/families/family.html#NegativeBinomial.get_distribution
where GLM parameters need to be transformed to correspond to the scipy distribution.

Comment: The difference parameterization should not matter to me, because I use the Fitter package to fit distributions by trial&error (which is based on scipy) and then choose the best fit for the GLM.